# Thread 1: Signal SIGBART Error

Tags: xcode, multithreading, xcode5, signals

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([StudentCouncilAppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

I am pretty new to XCode and just trying to create an app. However, when I run my code, it stops and says Thread 1: Signal SIGBART. I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to continue over it by debugging it, but then it crashes. Then when I try to read the debug error, none is there. Does anyone know how to fix this? Please help. 
I wish I could post a screenshot of it but I don't have enough reputation to...

At first it was working fine but after I put this code in

```
(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
  [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

For SIGABRT its mostly a access to an illegal address or illegal operation (divide by 0).  Check the registers, if you can.  Also, you could post some code of where the error is occurring.

Comment: I went into the debug area, and selected "All" in the bottom right corner. It shows me the General Purpose Register, the Floating Point Register,  and the Exception State Register. What do I do now?

Comment: @user3754646 have you got any solution for this...i am also getting same error while i am running app.