# thread 1: signal SIGABRT error upon building

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sigabrt, build-error

I don't know what I did wrong. I'm trying to add a RSS feed to another page (There is one of the startup page and one for the page I am working on now) but I don't know why this error is occurring. I have already made sure that all my connections on the storyboard are correct but I still get this issue upon loading. If anyone could help, that could be great.

I am making the app for my school which will include a calendar. I am trying to use a RSS feed to fetch events from a WordPress site, like I am currently doing with the news page of the site. After adding new view controllers and navigation controllers and connecting them to each Swift file, the app crashes upon clicking on the page in the sidebar menu. Both pages (Calendar RSS and News RSS) have separate files also.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/TheLamp/WSDAPP

Comment: Dude, post relevant code, don't make SO users download and hunt through a whole project. No one will and you won't get an answer. See this answer for general answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297393/thread-1-signal-sigbart-error

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y6qycF5E and http://pastebin.com/LbHp6TfD @noobsmcgoobs

Comment: Just post it in your question so it's searchable for anyone in the future who has the same problem.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs I can't because I don't know exactly where the error is and the code is too long to be inserted. Picture: http://imgur.com/thvZ9Ww

Comment: You need to edit your post to be clearer. At least describe better the structure of your app like what the user is supposed to do and what the outcome is supposed to be. At some point your app built, then you changed something. Describe what you changed and post that. There should also be an error message. Post that. SIGBART usually means you sent a message to an object that doesn't exist or that can't perform of pass on that message.

Comment: the most interesting part is missing in your screenshot. output of debug window!

Comment: @user3441734 Debug Output: http://pastebin.com/QCnZkmQd

Comment: '[<WSDAPP.TestCalViewController 0x7fe27118a8c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myTableView.' so, you have an idea, where to go and what to check ...

Comment: @user3441734 I still don't get what's wrong. After searching the whole .swift file, there is nothing referencing myTableView, only mytableView. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: that should be the trouble, typo myTableView vs mytableView (some outlet could be  missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by myself. After reading another post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087739/5113812) on Stack Overflow, I had too many assignings to my Table View which made it not work correctly.

Thanks for all the help everyone!